# Flexboxes of equal height, content filling height of container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Link to the site I'm editing for reference: http://securitysolutionsnw.businesscatalyst.com/fire-life-safety

Here's a CodePen of the thing:
http://codepen.io/Murgittroyd/pen/HqEvp

I have an unordered list of list items, and I'm trying to get each item to be the same width and height. I've started investigating and using flex-box, which helped, but I can't get the content of each box to fill the whole height of the list item. Essentially, I need boxes that are dynamically sized but by the size of the largest flexbox...anyone have any ideas?

HTML:

```
<ul class="box-list">
    <li>
        <div class="visual">
            <img src="/images/img07.jpg" width="281" height="187" alt="image description" />
            <div class="hover">
                <a href="/fire-life-safety/fire-extinguishers">
                    <span class="ico"><img src="/images/ico-fire-extinguishers-white-large.png" alt="image description" /></span>
                    <span class="text">Learn More</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>
                <span class="ico"><img src="/images/ico-fire-extinguishers-white.png" alt="image description" /></span>
                <span class="text">Fire Extinguishers</span>
            </h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc consectetur sed sem ac facilisis. Proin venenatis nisi ut  elit a scelerisque. </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#content .box-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -14px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
#content .box-list li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 14px 43px 0;
    width: 281px;
}
#content .box-list li:after {
    display: none;
}
#content .box-list .content {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 18px 20px 33px 33px;
    background: #232a32;
}
#content .box-list .visual {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: flexbox [still requires vendor prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) in many cases; there are a number of properties you might want to specify on the flex container, such as `align-content: stretch;` and `flex-direction: row;`. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/btr7gpqy/) is a working fiddle of flexboxes that stretch vertically to match largest item. [here](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) is a tool for learning about flexboxes

Comment: I think this won't be possible without some js sugar.

Comment: Oddly, setting the `line-height` to `0` on the `<li>` elements seems to work for me for getting the list item to hug its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not it's possible with pure CSS depends on your exact needs. If you just need to have each row of `li` items the same height, then you're already doing it correct. As you can see with any Element inspection tool, the `li` items in a row are all the same height (in my Chrome browser at least). However, the content of your `li` isn't scaled to fill the full height.

If you need EVERY element on the page the same height, you probably need some JS.

Comment: Do you think there's a way to have the content fill the full height of the parent element?

Comment: It really depends on how dynamic your content is, but you could for example just set the background color for you `li` so it would fill the entire box.

Answer (score 0):

So I've found a solution of sorts, just masking the entire `li` to appear the same as the `.content`, since (as [Wouter Florijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2622860/wouter-florijn) pointed out) the `li` were already the same heights due to using flex. Here's how I changed some CSS, basically just changed all `padding` into `margin` so `background-color` would fill the `li`:

```
#content .box-list li {
float: left;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
margin: 0px 14px 43px 0px;
width: 281px;
background-color: #232a32;
}
```